# jQuery Swapping Elements

Tags: jquery

Ok let me make an example:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#options_2").hide();
    $("#options_3").hide();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="options_1">option 1</div>
<div id="options_2">option 2</div>
<div id="options_3">option 3</div>
<a href="" class="selected">choose option 1</a>
<a href="">choose option 2</a>
<a href="">choose option 3</a>
</body>
```

As you can see only option 1 is visible by default, and the link you click to show option 1 has the class="selected" by default, showing the user that that option is currently selected. I basically want it so that when they click "choose option 2" the options 1 div hides itself and the options 2 div shows itself, and then gives the second link the selected class and removes the class from the image link.

It basically just tabs using links and divs but due to the format I have to display it in I cannot use any of the tabs plugins I have found online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all give your links a class or Id (I've used a class), which will make it easier to do the swap in

```
<div id="options_1" class="tab" >option 1</div>
<div id="options_2" class="tab">option 2</div>
<div id="options_3" class="tab">option 3</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var clickHandler = function (link) {
         $('.tab').hide();
         $('#option_' + link.data.id).show();
         $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).attr('class','selected');
   }

   $('.link1').bind('click', {id:'1'} ,clickHandler);
   $('.link2').bind('click', {id:'2'} ,clickHandler);
   $('.link3').bind('click', {id:'3'} ,clickHandler);
})
```

Comment: I thank you indefinately, after weeding out the spelling mistakes in your code it worked perfectly!

Comment: If you're using multiple classes per element,  $(this).attr('class','selected') is too clumsy as it removes all other classes except 'selected'.  Instead, use $(this).addClass('selected') and all other classes will remain in place.

Answer (score 2):

Given the format your given I'd do something like the following, assign each link with an id that can understandably refer to it's associated div (like "link_1" for "option_1") and use the following jQuery:

```
$('a#link_1').click(function() {
     $(this).attr("class", "selected");
     $(this).siblings('a').removeClass("selected");
     $('div#option_1').show();
     $('div#option_1').siblings('div').hide();
});
    $('a#link_2').click(function() {
     $(this).attr("class", "selected");
     $(this).siblings('a').removeClass("selected");
     $('div#option_2').show();
     $('div#option_2').siblings('div').hide();
});
    $('a#link_3').click(function() {
     $(this).attr("class", "selected");
     $(this).siblings('a').removeClass("selected");
     $('div#option_3').show();
     $('div#option_3').siblings('div').hide();
});
```

I haven't done jQuery for a little while, but that should be right :)

Comment: Not working but I'm not sure why, damn Java and it's lack of showing errors. Looking at the code it seems to make sense (even though I have only very recentley started exploring jQuery)...

Answer (score 1):

You can help yourself if you add IDs to your links in form 'options_1_select' and a class 'opener'. Then you can assign a single event handler to all of your links:

```
$('a.opener').click(function() {
  // mark current link as selected and unmark all others
  $(this)
    .addClass('selected')
    .siblings('a').removeClass('selected');

  // find a div to show, and hide its siblings
  $('#' + $(this).attr('id').substring(0, 9))
    .show()
    .siblings('div').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an accordion.

jQuery UI provides one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/