# div tags-on and off

Tags: hide, dreamweaver, show, html

Should be super simple for you guys...div one gets clicked, div two appears. What I don't know how to do is make div 2 go away when div one is clicked again.

```
<img src="/..." width="" height"" onClick="MM_showHideLayers('logo','','show','logoEasterEgg','',show')">
```

What should I add to this line of code to make the div 'logoEasterEgg' disappear when the image in div 1 is clicked again?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something similar to what was suggested in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233936/jquery-swapping-elements) question with jQuery.

Basically just have a class for the div which you add and remove based on whether it is already there.

Comment: jQuery has a toggle function 

$('#div1').toggle(
function() { $('#logoEasterEgg').show(); }, 
function() { $('#logoEasterEgg').hide(); });

Comment: thanks for this great tip. this will definitely come in handy

Answer (score 0):

<del>You are going to need to add another function call to hide the other div after the first call to show it.</del>

The onclick attribute would look something like this:

MM_showHideLayers('logo','','show','logoEasterEgg','',show');**hide_function();**

The onclick attribute will allow as much javascript as you like you you can stuff as many functions as you like in there - just don't forget your semicolons.

**Edit:**

After reading a bit about `MM_showHideLayers` I am thinking that you need to change the function to close the div that needs closing.  In other words if you want to close `logo` then make the onclick attribute (notice the **hide**):

MM_showHideLayers('logo','','**hide**','logoEasterEgg','',show');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using MM_showHideLayers() could you do something like this...?

```
function toggleDiv(divId)
{
  var myDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
  if (myDiv) 
  {
    if (myDiv.style.display === 'none') 
    {
      myDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
      myDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

<img src="/..." width="" height"" onClick="toggleDiv('logoEasterEgg')">
```